# WSS 3.0 Replacing text in hyperlink column

Tags: 2007

We have a hyperlink column we use in a list application to store file UNC file paths for the associated work item. We are now beginning a domain migration so the domain will change in the UNC path and leave the existing links broken. In looking at using a calculated column to create a new path a hyperlink column is not an available source.

Looking for either a script or a package that would allow the replacing of the text in the UNC paths in the hyperlink column with the new domain.

Example: replace aaa.local with zzz.local in the hyperlink UNC path

file://fileserver.aaa.local
file://fileserver.zzz.local

Any ideas would be appreciated. About 10,000 rows to modified

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated column and use below formula

```
=REPLACE([YourColumnname],FIND("aaa.local",[YourColumnname]),9,"zzz.local")
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I have tried I cannot create a calculated column using a hyperlink tyoe column as the source, at least from the sharepoint web interface. Is this something that can be done perhaps using SP Designer?